# 3d plotting of data analysis from a file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I need to compute 2 functions, `mutualinfo2d` and `mutualinfo3d` on data from files and get a 3d plots of these analysis.
I have to run over all the files that are indexed with 3 numbers:

The first and the third are parameters, these values change among the file names into two arrays, `mu` `krat` known and given.

The second number say the kind of file (is an input of my code)

So for each file I got back a number that has to be the value that I have to 3d plot referred to the parameters `mu` `krat` that characterized the file name.

So looping over the parameter I compute these functions put in a list and at the end I want a 3d plot where x, y are `mu` `krat` and z the values computed using my functions `mutualinfo2d` and `mutualinfo3d`.

I wrote a simple script that run on these files and analyze them correctly, I am able to make the 2d plot of my functions fixing one of the two parameter but I am not able to vary together and get back the 3d plot.

This is the code that I wrote to get 3d plot:

```
n= 0    # selected the folder to analyze


path="/storage1/monti/Desktop/info_topology/VaryingK_mu_GRN"

path= path + "%d/"%(n)

krat=[1,3,5,7,9,10,30,50,70,90,100,300,500,700,900,1000,3000,5000,7000,9000]

mu=[1,3,5,7,9,10,30,50,70,90,100,300,500,700,900]

mu = array(mu)
krat=array(krat)

inf0=[]
inf1=[]
inf2=[]
for j in mu:

    for k in krat:

        filename="InfoDati_"+"%lf_"%(j)+"%d_"%(n) +"%lf.txt"%(k) # InfoDati_mu_GRN_krat


        fil = path + filename

        data=loadtxt(fil)

        t=data[:,0]
        x=data[:,1]
        y=data[:,2]             # y, z should be the simulation, x the sin
        z=data[:,3]

        x=array(x)

        y=array(y)

        z=array(z)

        t=tran(t,T=24,dx=0.05)

        dx1=[0.05, 1] 

        dx2=[0.05,1,1]

        inf0.append(mutualinfo2d(t,x, dx=dx1[0],dy=dx1[1]))

        inf1.append(mutualinfo2d(t,y, dx=dx1[0],dy=dx2[1]))

        inf2.append(mutualinfo3d(t,y,z, dx2))



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
Y = krat
X = mu
X, Y = meshgrid(X, Y)   

Gx, Gy = gradient(inf0) # gradients with respect to x and y
G = (Gx**2+Gy**2)**.5  # gradient magnitude
N = G/G.max()

Gx1, Gy1 = gradient(inf1) # gradients with respect to x and y
G1 = (Gx1**2+Gy1**2)**.5  # gradient magnitude
N1 = G1/G1.max()

Gx2, Gy2 = gradient(inf2) # gradients with respect to x and y
G2 = (Gx2**2+Gy2**2)**.5  # gradient magnitude
N2 = G2/G2.max()

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, inf0, rstride=1, cstride=1,facecolors=cm.jet(N),linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
surf1 = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, inf1, rstride=1, cstride=1,facecolors=cm.jet(N1),linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
surf2 = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, inf2, rstride=1, cstride=1,facecolors=cm.jet(N2),linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)

m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
m.set_array(G)

m1 = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
m1.set_array(G1)

m2 = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
m2.set_array(G2)

plt.colorbar(m)
plt.colorbar(m1)
plt.colorbar(m2)
plt.show()
```

I got back different 3d plot empty... and I would like to have just one 3d plot but with the three different surfaces!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is probably before the `plot_surface` commands.

An example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# create some surfaces
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10, dtype='float'), np.arange(8, dtype='float'))
z1 = X+Y
z2 = X-Y
z3 = np.sin(Y / 8. * 2* np.pi)

N1 = z1 / z1.max()
N2 = z2 / z2.max()
N3 = z3 / z3.max()

# create the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z1, cstride=1, rstride=1, facecolors=plt.cm.jet(N1), linewidth=0, shade=False)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z2, cstride=1, rstride=1, facecolors=plt.cm.jet(N2), linewidth=0, shade=False)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z3, cstride=1, rstride=1, facecolors=plt.cm.jet(N3), linewidth=0, shade=False)
```

This gives what it should:

[image]

Check that your `inf0` and `N` (etc) are valid. If you have even a single `nan` in your gradient, the normalization (calculation of `N`) will give an array full of `nan`s, and then nothing is drawn.